# Are Vala and desktopcouch ready?

Tags: vala, couchdb

I have started writting rss reader in Vala, but I don't know, what database system should I use, I cannot connect to couchdb and sqlite works fine, but I would like use couchdb because of ubuntu one. I have natty with latest updates

```
public CouchDB.Session session;
    public CouchDB.Database db;
    public string feed_table = "feed";
    public string item_table = "item";
    public struct field {
        string name;
        string val;
    }

    // constructor
    public Database() {
    try {
    this.session = new CouchDB.Session();
     } catch (Error e) {
           stderr.printf ("%s a\n", e.message);
        }

    try {

         this.db = new CouchDB.Database (this.session, "test");
         } catch (Error e) {
           stderr.printf ("%s a\n", e.message);
        }

        try {
        this.session.get_database_info("test");
        } catch (Error e) {
           stderr.printf ("%s aa\n", e.message);
        }

         try {
          var newdoc = new CouchDB.Document ();
        newdoc.set_boolean_field ("awesome", true);
        newdoc.set_string_field ("phone", "555-VALA");
        newdoc.set_double_field ("pi", 3.14159);
        newdoc.set_int_field ("meaning_of_life", 42);
        this.db.put_document (newdoc);    // store document
        } catch (Error e) {
        stderr.printf ("%s aaa\n", e.message);
        }
```

reports

```
$ ./xml_parser rss.xmlCannot connect to destination (127.0.0.1) aa
Cannot connect to destination (127.0.0.1) aaa
```

Comment: OT: Don't know Vala, but wouldn't you run the whole code block in the try-clause and then catch all the different Errors? http://paste.ubuntu.com/555107/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a performance point of view, I'd just like to say that CouchDB perhaps isn't the fastest solution when compared to something more mature like SQLite. A gwibber comparison puts SQLite as *just* [10 times faster](http://blogs.nemein.com/people/piotras/view/1274453113.html).

Given that a RSS reader does a lot more `SELECT` than `INSERT`, this is something you need to be conscious of because it's going to effect your application's responsiveness.

---

In terms of your code, comparing it to [the "official" Vala+Couch sample](http://live.gnome.org/Vala/CouchDBSample), you're not passing in the connection details so I'm wondering if there's an issue with the auto-detect mechanism. Couch is started on a different port each time it runs but [you can get its current port through dbus](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=8155355&postcount=4):

```
dbus-send --session --print-reply --dest=org.desktopcouch.CouchDB / org.desktopcouch.CouchDB.getPortmethod return sender=:1.231 -> dest=:1.230 reply_serial=2
```

I don't know the Vala for that but manually finding out might help you get the initial connection done.

Comment: I write tutorial to my blog, I have used desktopcouch header file and I don't have to get port and so on (handled by function)